# Collapsible DIV in Mobile

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a block which is to be shown as-is in the web version. However, I want it in collapsed mode in the mobile version. How should I go about it?

I'm using AngularJS and can't figure out a way.

Here's my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
<div uib-collapse="!isCollapsed">
    <p>Some content that needs to be shown in the web version but this needs to be in collapsed mode in the mobile version</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to go about this would be to set the initial value of `isCollapsed` in your controller based on the current screen width. Something along the lines of:

```
isCollapsed = window.innerWidth < 720;
```

Comment: Let me play around with it and see that :)